# Filtered Lookup Meta-Data

Tags: managed-package, api, metadata, lookup-filter

I am using Sublime Text and Mavens Mate to bring meta-data into our Git repository. I recently added a Lookup filter to a packaged field (managed-released). The change went through in the org just fine. However when we refresh the .object file in MavensMate (or Ant for that matter) we are not getting any of the  attributes in the file. In fact it has not changed at all. Any ideas?

```
   <fields>
    <fullName>Distributor__c</fullName>
    <deleteConstraint>SetNull</deleteConstraint>
    <deprecated>false</deprecated>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>Distributor</label>
    <referenceTo>Account</referenceTo>
    <relationshipLabel>Account Keys (Distributor)</relationshipLabel>
    <relationshipName>Distributor_Account_Keys</relationshipName>
    <required>false</required>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
    <type>Lookup</type>
</fields>
```

Comment: Can you check the other object the filter references? See this... http://blog.nathanwisman.com/2012/01/retrieving-lookup-filters-via-metadata.html

Comment: Just also found this in the Metadata API reference, http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/namedfilter.htm, 'The namedFilter appears as a child of the target object of the associated lookup field.'. I don't (yet) use the wonderful Mavens Mate, but suspect (while it still uses the Metadata API) this is likely the reason your not seeing it on the object you expect. Let me know your findings! :)

Comment: Thanks Andrew - I think that did it. The <namedFilter> values are indeed on the target object, in my case Account.obj. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filtered lookup meta-data can be found on the object you are looking up to. In the XML example above, the  are found on the Account.object record.

Answer (score 1):

As of API version 30.0, lookup filters are defined as [`lookupFilter`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/customfield.htm#lookupfilter) attributes on the field containing the lookup filter, rather than a `namedFilter` attribute on the parent object.